# How to display a BLOB object (image) from sqlite3 with Python

Tags: python, image, sqlite, blob, binary-data

I saved an image as a BLOB in a sqlite3 database column profile - I summon the function insertBLOB with relevant info:

```
sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('image_try.db')
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        fullname TEXT,
        username TEXT,
        profile BLOB)""")

def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        blobData = file.read()
    return blobData

def insertBLOB(name, username, photo):
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('image_try.db')
    sqliteConnection.text_factory = str
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    sqlite_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO images
                              (fullname, username, profile) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"""

    empPhoto = convertToBinaryData(photo)
    data_tuple = (name, username, empPhoto)
    cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
```

I tried to access the image file (so I could display it in a Label) like this - by summoning the function readBlobData:

```
def writeTofile(data):
    # Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
    this = open(data, 'rb')
    this.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
    return this


def readBlobData(empId):
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('image_try.db')
        sqliteConnection.text_factory = str
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

        sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT * from images where id = ?"""
        cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query, (empId,))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        profile = record[0][3] #Blob object

        profile = writeTofile(profile)

        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(profile)
        image_label = Label(root, image=image)
        image_label.photo = image
        image_label.pack()
        cursor.close()
```

when I summon the function readBlobData I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/hilab/PycharmProjects/dafyProject/addimage.py", line 90, in 
<module>
readBlobData(1)
File "C:/Users/hilab/PycharmProjects/dafyProject/addimage.py", line 67, in 
readBlobData
profile = writeTofile(profile)
File "C:/Users/hilab/PycharmProjects/dafyProject/addimage.py", line 51, in 
writeTofile
this = open(data, 'rb')
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Do you have any idea what seems to be the problem? and how can I fix it? How can I access the BLOB object from the SQLite database and present it???

Comment: Do I have to save the Blob image from the database on my computer in order to display it? (I'm using a server with multiple clients)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback and the `CREATE TABLE` statement used to create the `images` table please.

Comment: I updated the question @snakecharmerb

Comment: `profile` in the database table is supposed to be the path to an image file on disk, is that right?

Comment: no, it's the 'binary-data' representation of the image. presenting the image using bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is telling us that something is going wrong in the `writeToFile` function, specifically when we try to open a file:

```
profile = writeTofile(profile)
File "C:/Users/hilab/PycharmProjects/dafyProject/addimage.py", line 51, in 
writeTofile
this = open(data, 'rb')
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

The value that we are passing to the function is the binary image data read from the database

```
profile = record[0][3]
```

In the function, we are trying to use this binary data as the name of the file that we are going to read from to get the binary data in some format.

```
def writeTofile(data):
    # Convert binary data to proper format and write it on Hard Disk
    this = open(data, 'rb')
    this.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
    return this
```

`tkinter.PhotoImage` expects the path to a file, according to its documentation, so we have to create a file from the image bytes.:

```
def writeTofile(data):
    # Write it to the Hard Disk
    # (ideally with a suitable name and extension)
    filename = 'myfile.img'
    with open('myfile.img', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
    return filename
```

And in `readBlobData`:

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=profile)
```

And then all should be well.